# Div floating left, another inline to the right

Tags: css

I have a feeling that this is the most fundamental of questions, and after 5 years of messing about with CSS, I should know the answer to it.

I have two `div`s with classes of `pane-node-field-imageown` and `pane-node-field-short-place-intro`. They are at the top of my page which is wrapped in a div with class `burr-flipped-content-inner`.

HTML

```
<div class="burr-flipped-content-inner burr-flipped-content-region-inner panel-panel-inner">
    <div class="panel-pane pane-entity-field pane-node-field-imageown">
        <div class="panel-separator"></div>
        <div class="panel-pane pane-entity-field pane-node-field-short-place-intro">
            <div class="panel-separator"></div>
            <div class="panel-pane pane-vtiews-panes pane-og-nodes-panel-pane-2">
            </div>
```

With the div that has the `pane-node-field-imageown` class, I would like to float it to the left.

CSS

```
.pane-node-field-imageown
{
    float:left;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I added the `inline-block` value as it seems to best suit. The problem is getting the `pane-node-field-short-place-intro` div to sit nicely to the right of the first block. It seems to want to hide behind it (although my text seems to sit ok). The only way I can get the desired behaviour is with this CSS to the second block:

```
.pane-node-field-short-place-intro {
    display: table;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.pane-node-field-short-place-intro .pane-content {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #444444;
    padding:10px;
}
```

This doesn't feel right. My page can be [viewed here for reference](http://onlineplac.es/komp-krap).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do this:

```
.pane-node-field-short-place-intro {
padding: 3px 5px 0 20px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: thanks Ralph thatsjust what i was after. i will have a wee read up on overflow when i get a chance.

Comment: Glad to help. `overflow: hidden` is very handy for a lot of things. In this case, it stops a non-floated element from wrapping around a floated element beside it, so it's a nice way of doing columns.

Answer (score 0):

jsFiddle - CSS Floats
http://jsfiddle.net/kn9RE/9/

CSS Normalize - Be sure to make the the **FIRST** referenced style sheet
http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

First off, you are over-engineering your front-end markup.  I say this because your current markup resembles "Div Spaghetti".  I would start by evaluating your html code as a whole, remove all CSS and get a solid feel for the structure of your page.  Although there are easy ways to go-about resolving this issue, its always best to analyze your code and ask yourself "can this be done with less markup?".  Don't jump to take the easy way out, you will often end up with a code-base full of poor habits.

If you **must** use your existing HTML, you could apply a band-aid to your problem like so;

```
.pane-node-field-imageown
{
float:left;
}

.pane-node-field-short-place-intro
{
max-width: 660px;
float:left;
padding: 10px 5px 0 15px;
}

.field-item even
{

}
```

This should get you started, if you have any questions Please feel free to message me.